# Why doesn't AJAX UpdatePanel work in ASP.NET 2.0 Web Site template?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I'm just getting into AJAX (little late I know) and am walking through some of the tutorials on the ASP.NET/AJAX site. One thing I've noticed is that I cannot get the UpdatePanel to work in the ASP.NET Web Site template. I can use the EXACT same markup, code, and web.config in the  AJAX 1.0-Enabled ASP.NET 2.0 template and everything works as expected.

Markup:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
               <asp:ScriptManager EnablePartialRendering="true"
                    ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
               <div>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"
                         UpdateMode="Conditional">
                         <ContentTemplate>
                              <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" /><br />
                              <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"
                                   Text="Update Both Panels" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                              <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server"
                                   Text="Update This Panel" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
                         </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server"
                         UpdateMode="Conditional">
                         <ContentTemplate>
                              <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" ForeColor="red" />
                         </ContentTemplate>
                         <Triggers>
                              <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
                         </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
               </div>
          </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}
```

I'll post the web.config if needed, but again, they are exactly the same (copy pasted). ANy help would be appreciated.

Comment: No error, but the entire page still posts back (I can see the IE progress bar working).

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the buttons out of the first update panel.  Also, try "ChildrenAsTriggers=true" inside the updatepanel tag.

Comment: BUt why does the code work without issue in the AJAX 1.0 Web Site template? The code is right because it works fine with that template.